# Changing an activities content view based on actionbar tabs

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, android-fragments

I am wondering if this can be done. Basically I have a layout with 2 fragments in it that I use for most of my tabs but on 2 of the tabs I want to add a couple more fragments to display more things. Is it possible to change the content view to a different layout when changing tabs?

If that cant be done I thought about creating a layout with all the fragment parts that I would need and just changing the layouts of the fragments so the ones I dont use wont "show". I dont mean using `FragmentTransaction.hide()` because I want the fragments to fill the screen when others are not used. Would that be a bad idea or is there an easier way to do what I want?

here is my code for the activity and tabs

```
public class Tabs extends Activity{
long deleteID;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle create){
    super.onCreate(create);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    createTabs();
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
    bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    if(create != null){
        bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(create.getInt("Home",0));
    }

}
```

I also add tabs a whatnot but thats not important

this is the actionbar subclass

```
private class TabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener{
    TabContent mFragment;

    public TabListener(TabContent fragment) {
        mFragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

            ListFragment newListFragment = new BowlersListFragment();
            Fragment newFragment = new BowlerEntryFrag();
            ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.frameOne, newListFragment);
            ft.replace(R.id.frameTwo, newFragment);

        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

        if(ft != null){
            ft.remove(mFragment);
        }
    }

}

}
```

I tried doing `Activity.setContentView(r.layout.newView)` but that won't work

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, so implemented it like this. I have a mainActivity that holds and creates the tabs. That activity uses a layout with one fragment container, main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my activity I have the following code for creating the tabs and fragments:

```
historyTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("History");
historyTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(new HistoryFragment()));
actionbar.addTab(historyTab);
```

My tabListener looks something like this:

```
    private class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    public Fragment fragment;
    private boolean isFragmentAdded = false;

    public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }
           @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

        FragmentManager fragMgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction xaction = fragMgr.beginTransaction();

        if (fragment instanceof HistoryFragment) {
            fragment = new HistoryFragment();
            xaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        } else if (fragment instanceof .. some other fragment..) {
            fragment = new .. some other fragment();
            xaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        } 
        }

        xaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

        FragmentManager fragMgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction xaction;

        xaction = fragMgr.beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment = fragMgr.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        xaction.remove(fragment);

        xaction.commit();
    }

}
```

The layout for the History fragment in my example, can be anything, even a layout that contains two fragments, or as much you need. Just be careful, and in onCreateview method in the fragment, use this:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle          
savedInstanceState) {
    if (view == null) { // this line is very important!
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_fragment_layout, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.historyList);
    }

    return view;
}
```

Hope that helps!:)